# how to change a macro function

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have gotten an excel file that includes reference to a function f(x,y). The file did not include the macro. I wrote a macro with a different function and saved it with an .xlsm extension. when I run the new macro I get a run time error '28' out of stack space error.

What does this mean and how do I correct? I was told I did not need visual basic to do this. Is this a special additional package? Thank you.

```
Sub xplusy()
'
' xplusy Macro
' Function f(x,y) f=x+y End Function
'

'
    Application.Run "'5_3 Runge-Kutta.xlsm'!xplusy"
    Sheets("RK4").Select
    Range("C9").Select
    Application.Run "'5_3 Runge-Kutta.xlsm'!xplusy"
    Range("E8").Select
    Application.CommandBars("Help").Visible = False
    Application.Goto Reference:="xplusy"
End Sub
```

Comment: Perhaps, the guy who told you that you didn't "need VBA to do this" knew what you were intending to do. We don't. Note that there is no such thing as "a reference to a function". Functions are called, not referenced. `Function f` has two parameters, x and y. It returns `x + y`. `Application.Goto Reference:="xplusy"` requires that there should be a named range "xplusy" in your workbook. The code will select that range. It is unrelated to the `Sub xplusy()` which calls a sub by that same name in workbook "5_3 Runge.Kutta.xlsm" repeatedly, perhaps itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling the function `xplusy()`, which is calling the function `xplusy()`, which is calling the function `xplusy()`, which is calling the function `xplusy()`, ....
Each time you call a function, its reference is added to the so-called `stack`, so you are overloading that stack, explaining the error message.

In the original file, you should check the name of the macro, and the macro you're calling (they definitely should be different).

Comment: I just opened up the xlsm file. The macro is now not editable, will only run ie cannot be edited, and the name has been changed (filename is added to the beginning of macro name). My macros are being changed when I save? –

Comment: That should be the case, yes.

Answer (score 2):

Let's pare your Sub down to the very basic level:

```
Sub VeryBasic()
    Application.Run "VeryBasic"
    Application.Run "VeryBasic"
    Application.GoTo "Location"
End Sub
```

Now, see how that code *calls itself*?  If we expand it 1 level, we get this:

```
Sub VeryBasic()
    'Application.Run "VeryBasic"
        Application.Run "VeryBasic"
        Application.Run "VeryBasic"
        Application.GoTo "Location"
    'Application.Run "VeryBasic"
        Application.Run "VeryBasic"
        Application.Run "VeryBasic"
        Application.GoTo "Location"
    Application.GoTo "Location"
End Sub
```

Expand it 2 levels:

```
Sub VeryBasic()
    'Application.Run "VeryBasic"
        'Application.Run "VeryBasic"
            Application.Run "VeryBasic"
            Application.Run "VeryBasic"
            Application.GoTo "Location"
        'Application.Run "VeryBasic"
            Application.Run "VeryBasic"
            Application.Run "VeryBasic"
            Application.GoTo "Location"
        Application.GoTo "Location"
    'Application.Run "VeryBasic"
        'Application.Run "VeryBasic"
            Application.Run "VeryBasic"
            Application.Run "VeryBasic"
            Application.GoTo "Location"
        'Application.Run "VeryBasic"
            Application.Run "VeryBasic"
            Application.Run "VeryBasic"
            Application.GoTo "Location"
        Application.GoTo "Location"
    Application.GoTo "Location"
End Sub
```

**Hopefully** you can see that this code will keep getting bigger and bigger, without actually doing *anything* except adding another copy of itself to the "Stack" to run.  Eventually, your stack will run out of room (or your computer will run out of memory), and you get a [Stack overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_overflow) error.

Comment: I just opened up the xlsm file. The macro is now not editable, will only run ie cannot be edited, and the name has been changed (filename is added to the beginning of macro name). My macros are being changed when I save?